# Animating an svg with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, snap.svg

I need to animate (using css) an SVG but I do not want to embed all of the SVG code into the page.

After looking at ways to include my svg in the page and still being able to animate it the only way I could find that did not embed the svg raw data was to use an object, but any css that animated the svg needed to be included in style tags or linked to from the svg file. This was not really an option for me.

I then looked at Snap which worked well, but then I found I could just load the external file via jquery and animate using CSS:

```
$('.mysvg').load('path/to/my-svg.svg');
```

My question is, is there any limitations or things I should look out for doing it this way? Have I missed something obvious, I saw no examples of doing it this way when reading through countless blog posts about svg animation.

Comment: It depends on what type of css animation. You may want to check browser support on any specific thing you want to do if css3 as implementations aren't consistent currently. You lose a fine grain of control as opposed to Snap, but you may not need it. It may also depend if you have interactions with the mouse, then things like css transforms may need extra thought. Basically, more info would be needed to know if there are any drawbacks in your case.

Comment: Im just using simple transforms like: transform: translateY(20%); So I need not use snap then? Just use jquery to load the image and then use css to animate?

Comment: I can't remember if jquery can animate css on svg, there may be jquerysvg otherwise. Basic transform should be ok, if you need something like transform-origin for things like rotations though, you may find inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to animate SVGs with any of the CSS3 features like `transition` or `animation`. `<svg>` is treated the same way as normal DOM elements so as long as they have the proper classes and they do not have any `style` attributes that may override the CSS, you should be good. There's a good presentation [here](http://slides.com/sarasoueidan/styling-animating-svgs-with-css#/8) that talks about embedded styles, and what to look out for.

Also regarding your first point, you can technically do that but ideally the only real benefit is it cleans up your HTML so you don't see it. Doing it this way requires you to wait for JavaScript to load and the container to be in the DOM before it can load your SVG. You CAN inline your SVG but like you said you don't want to. This is why people use PHP which is server-side and from there they can do stuff like

```
<div class="mysvg">
    <?php include_once("path/to/my-svg.svg") ?>
</div>
```

So that way it's still sectioned off but it isn't loaded dynamically by the client.

It feels icky to put SVG directly in your HTML code but I would argue it's one of the most awesome things about SVGs.

Comment: Surely the other benefit is caching the image? Using coded inline will not cache?

Comment: @panthro it's not an image though and that's an important distinction. -- when you use the `load` function, you are inserting it as if it were code. Straight from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) -- _Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element_.